# convert a sentence to an object with Key/Value Format js

Tags: javascript

I have a sentence like below:

```
mySentence = "12,alex \n" +"22,zac \n" +"41,sara \n" +"33,mike \n"
```

and want to convert into an object like below:

```
{
"12":"alex",
"22":"zac",
"41":"sara",
"33":"mike"
}
```

any solution would be my appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the solution you tried?

Comment: Your sentence is a CSV-like string. Here is an [example](https://sebhastian.com/javascript-csv-to-array/) how to parse CSV. Function `csvToArray` is what you looking for

Comment: This should do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/yg3bxLc9/1/ the .split() method can create arrays from strings based on a delimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
var mySentence = "12,alex \n" +"22,zac \n" +"41,sara \n" +"33,mike \n"
mySentence = Object.fromEntries(mySentence.trim().split(' \n').map(v => v.split(',')))
console.log(mySentence)
```

Comment: I'd probably not rely on white space in the splits but trim later `mySentence.trim().split('\n').map(p => p.split(',').map(s => s.trim()))` (also accounts for possible spaces before or after commas)

Comment: If the format of `mySentence` is guaranteed to end with " \n", then I see no reason to add an extra `.map(s => s.trim())`. But if not then, your approach is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
const mySentence = "12,alex \n" +"22,zac \n" +"41,sara \n" +"33,mike \n";
const object = {};
mySentence.split('\n').filter(e => e != '').forEach(e => {
  const str = e.trim().split(',')
  const key = str[0];
  const value = str[1];
  object[key] = value;
});
console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a package like QS or https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill to support any browsers like IE and Node.js as well.

Comment: It would be more helpful if an example could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean

```js
let mySentence = "12,alex \n" +"22,zac \n" +"41,sara \n" +"33,mike \n"
let sentenceObj = {}

mySentence
  .split('\n') // split the string
  .filter(Boolean) // filter out all empty items
  .forEach(v => { // build the object
    sentenceObj[v.split(',')[0]] = v.split(',')[1].trim() //key with value trimmed
  });

console.log(sentenceObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const a = "12,alex \n" +"22,zac \n" +"41,sara \n" +"33,mike \n";

const b = a.split('\n').reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
  if(curr) {
    const [key, value] = curr.split(',');
    return {
      ...prev,
      [`${key}`]: value
    }
  }
    return prev;
  
}, {});

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createObject(sentence){
let arr = sentence.split(' \n');
let obj = {};
arr.forEach(ai => {
  let parsed = ai.split(',')
  if (parsed.length == 2) {
      obj[parsed[0]] = parsed[1];
  }
})
return obj
}
let sentence = "12,alex \n" + "22,zac \n" + "41,sara \n" + "33,mike \n";
console.log(createObject(sentence));
```

You can use the above function for conversion